# Smack - When to call MultiUserChat.Join(...)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, muc

I'm a bit confused and can't find the answer in the [docs](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html).
I'm developing a simple chat app for Android.
I've created a group (muc) and everything works, but do I have to keep calling join() everytime I open the app?

I've noticed that it doesn't work otherwise..
Don't understand why since the server knows that my jabberID is connected to this muc.

Hope my question is clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (I Hope) complete explanation: short answer is yes.

When a persistent room is created on your server, and you logout or exit the room, you have to re-join each time.
A logout or connection lose is obvious, but when you exit (leave) the room, you also won't receive messages directly from it (even though your still connected to the server), the server knows your id is **affiliated** with that MUC (as a member for example), but you're not **inside** it, for further info refer to [the XEP about MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), and also read about how your specific server implements it on your server docs (probably saves messages under a room-to-offline users, or something similar).

That is basically what happens in WhatsApp when you go in and out of group chats, but they also have their own custom way (the layer they built on top of the basic xmpp server) to let you know about unread messages, that includes **both** a service (you can see it in your phone in the general settings->apps) **and** push notifications.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I meant.
I don't think I'll use a service though, it's a good solution, because you can't implement background services in IOS as well and I want to develop the same app for both platforms...

Comment: it's perfectly fine, In my work we didn't use a service either because of the same reason (parallel IOS app), instead we use are own webservice combined with [Parse](https://parse.com/), to cover that, push notifications usually creates the user-app interaction pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Service
2. Add your xmpp code in it, like login, one to one chat, MUC chat.

So even your app closed service will remain in background and you will be always connected to chatrooms.

Comment: I can use push notifications instead, but that wasn't my question.
I asked if I should join a muc only once when I create it (or invited to it), or everytime a xmpp connection is established (for example when opening the app or booting the phone..)

Comment: Yes you have to join everytime when app loose connection with server, You must have to maintain connection with server, that's why you need to implement Service (create broadcast listener on phone boot to start your Service to initialize your connections)